# How to connect Apache Phoenix-4.2.1 to eclipse IDE in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, apache-phoenix

I am new to Phoenix 
I have connected my Apache Phoenix to HBase and it all going well trough terminal but i need to perform some operation of java on table so can you help me to fix how can i connect my phoenix to eclipse IDE so that i can perform operation from phoenix to HBase table and update that table in HBase.
Please help me to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I set it up using Eclipse Data Tools.

Install Eclipse Data Tools

Create generic_JDBC_1.x driver in:

In windows/perferences/DataManagement/Connectivity/Driver Definition:

Select Add

In Jar list, point to phoenix-version-client.jar

Next, in the properties tab, select the URL for the connection. The format is:

jdbc:phoenix:zookeepers:/hbase-unsecure

The Zookeeper node in my case is /hbase-unsecure because I have set it up in Ambari and that is the default. It could be only /hbase in your setup. This is set in hbase-site.xml.

For driver class, I selected org.apache.phoenix.jdb.PhoenixDriver

Next step, open Data Source Explorer view and connect to your database.

Now, when you open a SQL file, specify your connection details, i.e., Generic JDBC_1.x,  Name, database

To run your SQL script, simply right click in the editor and select Execute current text.

Behdad

ExaPackets LLC

Comment: How do I install eclipse data tools in linux?